# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath

Tags: java, testing, selenium

I have tried to create the testing framework using [this tutorial](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/testng-framework-selenium-tutorial-12/)

While executing the code, I am getting the below exception. Please tell me what I need to do with my code and Java configuration.

```
org.testng.TestNGException:
```

> Cannot find class in classpath: sampletest

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Eclipse? Try `Project`->`Clean` and run again. I have seen similar behaviour before for various users.

Comment: Even i clean the project and run again , i am getting the same issue.